# How to best handle multiple tasks accessing the same mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, concurrency

So, I have multiple tasks that lock/release the same mutex. After reading this:

> While a mutual-exclusion lock is held, code executing in the same
>   execution thread can also obtain and release the lock. However, code
>   executing in other threads is blocked from obtaining the lock until
>   the lock is released.
>   [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-lock-statement)

I got a bit nervous. This should mean two tasks can access the same mutex if they're scheduled on the same thread?

For context, I will have one long-running task (could be replaced by a thread) and multiple small tasks that access the same mutex.

To clarify, this is what I'm worried about:

Thread 0:

```
 Run Task 1: Lock mutex, do some work

 Pause Task 1

 Run Task 2: Lock mutex, do some work, release mutex

 Run Task 1: keep doing work, release mutex
```

Comment: Yeah in general mutexes are risky with tasks. Is there any reason why you can't use the `SemaphoreSlim`? (it even has an awaitable lock method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are concerned that [the program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KB1jyB) below would be buggy, and would not report the correct final value 1,000,000 for the counter:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int TASKS_COUNT = 1000;
        const int LOOPS_COUNT = 1000;
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 10); // Ensure that we have more threads than cores
        var locker = new object();
        var counter = 0;
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, TASKS_COUNT).Select(async x =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS_COUNT; i++)
            {
                await Task.Yield();
                lock (locker)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {counter:#,0}");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Counter: 1,000,000

The reason that this program is correct is because a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread that is interrupted by the operating system in the middle of calculating the non-atomic `counter++` line, it will resume with the same calculation when it receives its next time-slice from the operating system. The [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) will not schedule another task to run in the same thread, before the previous task running on that thread has been completed.

It's worth noting that from the point of view of the `TaskScheduler`, each code path between two `await` operators constitutes a separate mini `Task`. The splitting is done be the async state machine. In the example program above 1,000 tasks are created explicitly, but the actual number of tasks created by the async state machine in total is 1,000,000. All these tasks were scheduled through the [`TaskScheduler.Current.QueueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.queuetask) method.

Comment: When discussing concurrency issues, it is not enough to run a concurrent system once without detecting an error (at least not when it is about **real** systems that may include some aleatoric jitter that differs between two test runs). That is, your positive result `Output: Counter: 1,000,000` gives hope that it can work in general, but there it doesn't contribute anything to a proof. We need a systematic argument.

Comment: @HelpingHand the explanation of why the program is correct is included in my answer. I've attempted to provide a high level, intuitive explanation, instead of a rigorous one based on citations from the C# specification (because 1. life is too short and 2. my name isn't Jon Skeet). You are right though that the correctness of the program is not proved by the correctness of a single execution. It wouldn't even be proved be 1,000,000 correct executions in each of 1000 different computer systems.

Comment: I'm not blaming you for not having provided an entire proof (for the reasons you mentioned, to which I agree). However, I have seen concurrent programs fail with unstable overall results in the integrated system, due to detail concurrency problems that you couldn't have detected in tests on a small component of the system. Therefore, my personal opinion on useful concurrency-proof design is very strict (and, I admit, a bit narrow-minded).

Comment: @HelpingHand if you were tasked with proving that the above program is correct, how would you do it?

Comment: I would have to inspect the specifications of the schedular and the different APIs the program uses (quite a lot of work, I agree!). The point is, the concurrency behaviour depends critically on statistical events (some data access being in time to disturb - or not). Therefore, we can't state freedom of such errors based on physical arguments (plenty of testing), but only based on mathematical arguments.

Answer (score 4):

This should be fine unless you are using async/await inside the critical section. This is because no other task can run on the thread until it completes execution of its current task.

If you are using awaits inside critical sections there can be a problem since "await" may complete the execution as far as the thread is concerned. The simple solution would be to not use await inside a critical section, and this is probably a good idea in general. If you have some specific problem with this it might be a good idea to post it as a new question.